# Comparing buried list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying following code:

```
disease(flu, [fever, chills, nausea]).
disease(cold, [cough, runny_nose, sore_throat]).
disease(hungover, [headache, nausea, fatigue]).

getSymptoms([Symptom|List]):-
    writeln('Enter Symptom:'),
    read(Symptom),
    dif(Symptom,stop),
    getSymptoms(List),
    intersection(disease(_,List1), List, Outlist).

getSymptoms([]).
```

The entry method is from: [Creating a list from user input with swi-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710213/creating-a-list-from-user-input-with-swi-prolog)

The user starts with:

```
getSymptoms(L).
```

I need to collect patients symptoms (say following are entered: fever, chills)

I then need to compare this list with symptom list of each disease and find out how many symptoms are common between 2 lists.

The `getSymptoms(L)` is collecting symptoms all right but is not giving intersection and returning an empty list:

```
?- getSymptoms(L).
Enter Symptom:
|: fever.
Enter Symptom:
|: stop.
L = [].
```

Following also did not work:

```
intersection(findall(L,disease(_,L),Out), List, Outlist).
```

How can I correct this? Thanks for your help.

Edit: with code suggested by @wouter_beek, I get:

```
disease(_, List1),
sort(List1, SList1),
sort(List, SList),
intersection(SList1, SList, OutList).

?- getSymptoms(L).
Enter Symptom:
|: fever.
Enter Symptom:
|: cough.
Enter Symptom:
|: stop.
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever, cough] ;
L = [fever] ;
L = [fever] ;
L = [fever] ;
L = [].
```

I want disease with number of common symptoms to be shown.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The code you are showing, with Wouter Beek's changes, doesn't generate the results you are showing. Please be clear about what code you actually tried and the actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `intersection/3` predicate as if it is a function:

```
intersection(findall(L,disease(_,L),Out), List, Outlist).
```

But this is not how Prolog works.  `intersection(X, Y, Z)` denotes a relation between three sets.  `findall(L, disease(_, L), Out)` does not denote a set.  `Out` is a list, but not necessarily a set.  You can use `sort/2` for that.

You should do something similar with the following line:

```
intersection(disease(_,List1), List, Outlist).
```

to:

```
disease(_, List1),
sort(List1, SList1),
sort(List, SList),
intersection(SList1, SList, OutList).
```

Comment: It is not working. If I enter fever and cough, I get 9 lists of [fever, cough] and 3 lists of [fever], and that too not together but one after the other on pressing ';'. Also, why is sort needed?

Comment: @mso I believe I mentioned in a comment to you in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136163/getting-number-of-common-items-between-lists-in-prolog#38143520) you had that you cannot use Prolog predicates as if they were functions. They do not work that way.

Comment: I am slowly understanding it. I corrected the intersection part but I could solve the above problem only after changing the user input routine. Hence, I did not follow-up on this question. Also, why is sort needed before intersection? I see that intersection works even without sorting.

Comment: @rnso Intersection works on sets not lists.  Try `intersection([a,b,a], [b,a,b], Set)` which results in `Set = [a,b,a]` IIRC.

Comment: Which function should I use to get answer as [a,b] ?

Comment: @mso Just query the Prolog top-level, i.e. `?- intersection([a,b,a], [b,a,b], Set).`