# Input list not obtained in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am using following code:

```
item(a, b, c).
item(a, a, c).
item(a, d, c).
item(a, c, b).

main:-
    getItems(L),
    writeln('-----------1-------------'),
    writeln(L),
    findall((A,B,C), item(A,B,C), M),
    writeln('-----------2-------------'),
    compareItem(M,L,I),
    writeln('-----------3-------------'),
    writeln(I).

getItems([Item|List]):-
    writeln('Enter:'),
    read(Item),
    dif(Item,stop),
    getItems(InputList).

getItems([]).

compareItem([H|T],L,Out):-
    writeln('-----------4-------------'),
    intersection(H,L,I),
    writeln('-----------5-------------'),
    compareItem(T,L,[I|Out]).
compareItem([],L,Out).
```

It gives following output:

```
?- main.
Enter:
|: a.
Enter:
|: b.
Enter:
|: stop.
-----------1-------------
[a|_G1003]
-----------2-------------
-----------4-------------
-----------1-------------
[a|_G1003]
-----------2-------------
-----------4-------------
-----------1-------------
[]
-----------2-------------
-----------4-------------
false.

4 ?-
```

The input method has been taken from: [Creating a list from user input with swi-prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710213/creating-a-list-from-user-input-with-swi-prolog)

I get following when commands are run separately:

```
?- findall((A,B,C), item(A,B,C), M)
M = [ (a, b, c), (a, a, c), (a, d, c), (a, c, b)].
?- intersection([a,b,c],[a,b],I).
I = [a, b].
```

However, it is [(a,b,c),...] in M and I expected user input to be [a,b] (here it is blank).

I want the output to be the intersection of user input with each of items in M:

```
[(a,b), (a,a), (a), (a,b)]
```

Also, after reaching point 4, how does the execution reach again point 1?

How can these be corrected? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(a,b,c)` is not a list in Prolog. It's a term which represents the canonical form: `','(a,','(b,c))`. A list `[a,b,c]` represents the canonical form, `'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,[])))`. `(a,b,c)` will simply not behave like a list so will not give you the results you are seeking.

If you want to handle your collection as lists, then use `findall([A,B,C], item(A,B,C), M)`.

```
compareItem([H|T],L,[I|Out]):-
    writeln('-----------4-------------'),
    intersection(H,L,I),
    writeln('-----------5-------------'),
    compareItem(T,L,Out).
compareItem([],_,[]).
```

Two other issues with the original predicate which are fixed above are:

1. The base case needs to indicate that the empty list `[]` is the result of comapring with the empty list. Otherwise, `Out` is never instantiated.
2. You have misplaced the `I` variable in the recursion, as it needs to be the head of the 3rd argument in the *result*, not in the recursive call.

You can, in fact, use `maplist` for this task:

```
compareItem(M, L, Out) :-
    maplist(intersection(L), M, Out).
```

This will be missing your `writeln` calls. You can add one back if you wish:

```
intersect_with_writeln(A, B, R) :-
    writeln('-----------4-----------'),
    intersect(A, B, R).

compareItem(M, L, Out) :-
    maplist(intersect_with_writeln(L), M, Out).
```

Comment: Why have you kept "[I|Out]" in recurse call of compareItem function and not in its header- pl see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177232/simple-square-program-in-prolog

Comment: Also, after reaching point 4, how does the execution reach again point 1?

Comment: Actually, compareItem([[a,b,c],[a,b,d],[c,b,d]], [c,d], L) (without maplist) does not work.

Comment: I think, you just copied my own function, which now I know is not correct.

Comment: @mso there were a couple of items I neglected to fix in your original *predicate* (not *function*) what I edited in my answer. In the base case you need to have the empty list `[]` instead of `Out`. Otherwise, `Out` is never instantiated. Your predicate also has the same issue with the misplaced variable that joel67 [cited here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177232/simple-square-program-in-prolog#38177759), which I also fixed in my edit.

Comment: The code works perfectly with these changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You only get the first element because you never use the list that contains the rest:

```
getItems([Item|List]):-
    writeln('Enter:'),
    read(Item),
    dif(Item,stop),
    getItems(InputList).
```

See the too bolded variables? They have different names but they need to have the same one, otherwise you're just discarding `InputList` and "returning" a free `List` from `getItems/1`.

You could have seen that mistake when compiling your program: your Prolog distribution probably said something along the line of:

```
Singleton variables: [List,InputList]
```

Which means that both those variables are only used once in a rule, and is therefore probably a mistake.

Comment: Thanks. The input part is working now but still it is not comparing properly, since M=[ (a,b,c), (a,a,c), (a,d,c), (a,c,b)] and input is [a,b]. How can I compare [a,b] with each of 4 lists of M?