# Simple square program in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Why is following simple program not working?

```
main :-
    squares([1,2,3,4,5], L),
    writeln(L).

squares([H|T], Outl) :-
    Sq is H*H,
    squares(T, [Sq|Outl]).
squares([], []).
```

The output is:

```
?- main.
false.
```

Replacing `Outl` with `[Outl]` ( in `squares([H|T], Outl)` ) does not help.

Using `=` and `#=` instead or `is` also did not help.

Nor did `squares([], P)` instead of `squares([], [])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you have written

```
squares([H|T],Outl):-
    Sq is H*H,
    squares(T,[Sq|Outl]).
```

Sq is misplaced, you should write

```
squares([H|T],[Sq|Outl]):-
    Sq is H*H,
    squares(T,Outl).
```

You add Sq at the result of the computation of the rest of the list T.

Comment: Is it working on your system? To me, it is giving:  ?- squares([1,2,3,4,5],L).
L = [1|_G1159].

Comment: Yes, it works. You should change Out1 to Outl (letter l not number 1). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a great candidate for `maplist`.

Define squaring of one element:

```
squared(X, XX) :- XX #= X * X.
```

Then apply `maplist`:

```
squared_list(L, LL) :- maplist(squared, L, LL).
```

By using `#=` here instead of `is/2`, it's behavior is more relational:

```
| ?- squared_list([1,2,3], L).

L = [1,4,9]

yes
| ?- squared_list(L, [1,4,9]).

L = [1,2,3] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```